# Convert NSData to a NSURL

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have seen this done the other way. But I have a NSData object returned that is suppose to be a URL of an image file.

How do I do this convert a NSData object into a NSURL?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to convert the NSData object to an NSString object and then you can just create a NSURL with the new string.

```
 NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // Or any other appropriate encoding
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString autorelease]];
```

Comment: Yea I tried :

`NSURL *imageUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`   but it returns null `NSLog(@"imageUrl=%@",[imageUrl absoluteString]);`

Comment: The location for the redirect is in the HTTP header not in the site content which can be possibly anything.

Comment: @elliotrock: What do you get from just `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`?

Comment: it crashes with that encoding. Prefers:
`NSUTF16StringEncoding` but I have a feeling my http call isn't formattted correctly. Been trying to figure out how to see a complete http call with either NSMutableURLRequest or via Profiling in instruments. No luck so far.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing same issue. Please help!

Comment: @April yes I used the NSUTF16StringEncoding. Try that or other formats, its dependent on the encoding format of what is returned.